# Do ORMLite persisters work in Android?

Tags: android, ormlite

Do custom persisters work on Android? I was trying to write one for an entity, and was having no luck in having it run when the entity gets written by the DAO. So, I tried to use the "MyDatePersister" from the examples and I am not able to get that working either.

The persister is nearly identical to the example one -> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/datapersister/MyDatePersister.java

In my entity, I have

```
@DatabaseTable
public class ClickCount implements Serializable {
    // other declarations
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DATE_FIELD_NAME, persisterClass = MyDatePersister.class)
    private Date lastClickDate;
    // more code
}
```

Here is a link to the whole project in Bitbucket -> https://bitbucket.org/adstro/android-sandbox. It's basically one of the ORMLite Android examples with the custom persister example added.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, what is the error result you're getting?

I got my custom persister to work just fine, though I didn't try to extend the DateType. Below is a JSONArrayPersister I found the need for. The confusing part is in the naming of the methods, but once they're setup properly, it should be ok.

```
package com.example.acme.persister;

import com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.SqlType;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.types.BaseDataType;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.DatabaseResults;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JSONArrayPersister extends BaseDataType {

    public static int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1024;

    private static final JSONArrayPersister singleTon = new JSONArrayPersister();

    public static JSONArrayPersister getSingleton() {
        return singleTon;
    }

    private JSONArrayPersister() {
        super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[] { String.class });
    }

    protected JSONArrayPersister(SqlType sqlType, Class<?>[] classes) {
        super(sqlType, classes);
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseDefaultString(FieldType fieldType, String defaultStr) {
        try {
            return new JSONArray(defaultStr);
        } catch (JSONException ex)
        {
            return new JSONArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return new JSONArray( results.getString(columnPos) );
        } catch (JSONException ex)
        {
            return new JSONArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object resultStringToJava(FieldType fieldType, String stringValue, int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        return parseDefaultString(fieldType, stringValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDefaultWidth() {
        return DEFAULT_WIDTH;
    }
}
```

Then in your entity:

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = JSONArrayPersister.class)
private JSONArray something;
```